# Tuple with Individual element

Tags: swift, xcode, tuples

I have below syntax for Tuple with individual values

```
let http200Status = (statusCode: 200, description: "OK")
print("The status code is \(http200Status.statusCode)")

// Prints "The status code is 200"
```

Now if I change my individual value as

```
    let http200Status = (Code: 200, Code: "OK")
    print("The status code is \(http200Status.0)"). // 200
    print("The status code is \(http200Status.1)"). // 0k

    print("The status code is \(http200Status.Code)") // it prints 200
    print("The status code is \(http200Status.Code)") // it prints 200 always why not value Ok
```

**My Question : Why it always take first value of Code ? not second ?**

[image]

Comment: I the compiler actually allows you to assign the same name to multiple tuple elements, how do you expect it to distinguish between them later? I'd actually consider this a compiler bug, at the very least this should produce a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting same-named tuple labels is a bug ([SR-8974](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8974)). It has been fixed in Swift 5.1. From the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Duplicate tuple element labels are no longer allowed, because it leads to incorrect behavior.

Xcode 11 (beta 6) correctly complains:

```
let http200Status = (Code: 200, Code: "OK")
// Error: Cannot create a tuple with a duplicate element label
```